# Is the cppreference definition of non-static data member wrong?

Tags: c++, language-lawyer

Definition from [cppreference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/data_members):

> Non-static data members are the variables that are declared in a member specification of a class.

And they have the example:

```
class S
{
   int& r;               // non-static data member of reference type
};
```

But we know that non-static data member references are not variables because of the Standard:

> §3/6: A variable is introduced by the declaration of a reference other than a non-static data member or of an object.

So is their definition of non-static data member wrong (they forgot about this exception)? Where I can find correct definition of the term "non-static data member"?

*Unfortunately I couldn't find a definition of non-static data member in the C++ Standard.*

**EDIT**: From [cppreference object definition](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/object) and discussion below we can conclude that non-static data members are not objects at all. And [cppreference non-static member page](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/data_members) corrected the discussed definition at the moment.

Comment: If you declare `r` as a non-static class member then it's still a non-static member *variable*. It just happens to be a variable that references something else. If you had that definition as a "normal" function-local variable, would you still say it's not a variable?

Comment: r is a variable - its value is the address of an int, exactly like a pointer. It's just syntactic sugar for pointers with some extra safety features

Comment: References are not *objects*, but they can be variables.

Comment: Standart 3.6: "A variable is introduced by the declaration of a reference other than a non-static data member or of an object."
I think this statement claims that non-static data member references are not variables. Am I wrong?

Comment: “non-static data member” is defined in §9.2/4. I don’t understand how to interpret §3/6 in this light.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude C++ Standard says that it is not true.

Comment: Non-reference non-static data member definitions don't introduce variables either, so, yes, the wording on cppreference is incorrect in general, not just for references.

Comment: @bogdan What makes you say that? The standard is quite explicit that non-static data members are objects, and that object declarations introduce variables.

Comment: @KonradRudolph Where does it say that?

Comment: @bogdan In §3/6 and §9.2/4.

Comment: @bogdan see §1.8/2, for example. Data member (excluding references) is a member subobject. And every subobject is an object so data member (excluding references) is object.

Comment: A nonref data member is not a subobject. There will be a subobject once you create an object of the enclosing class, only.

Comment: @KonradRudolph We have to be very careful with terminology here. A non-reference non-static data member definition does not define an object (just like the enclosing class definition doesn't define an object of that class); it defines a class member, period. Think about it this way: member subobjects need an enclosing object, otherwise, what are they *sub*objects of? Yes, when an object of the enclosing class is defined, then that definition defines its member subobjects as well; different ones for each object. The non-static member definition doesn't define any of those subobjects.

Comment: @bogdan Right on. That explains OP’s confusion as well.

Comment: In other words, there is a "1:n" relationship between a data member and its objects/references.

Comment: @JohannesSchaub-litb This makes sense, but the wording of the standard is then inexact, because it literally uses “is a”: “A non-static data member of non-reference type is a member subobject of a class object”. This should then rather be “corresponds to”, shouldn’t it?

Comment: In a similar way that a class declaration can "become" a complete object or subobject with 1:n relationship from the class type to objects of its type.

Comment: @konrad i agree, it seems sloppy wording use

Comment: Another complication is the definition of "object declaration" which afaik covers declararions of references (!) and objects as simple-declarations. However data member declararions are not simple-declarations, so they would not be "object declarations". But maybe they are still declarations of objects if of nonreference type...

Comment: Cppreference, like any wiki, has a talk tab on every page, which is more appropriate for this.  Dropped "variable" for now pending the outcome of this discussion.

Comment: From [cppreference for object](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/object): "The following entities are not objects: value, reference, function, enumerator, type, **class member**, bit-field, template, template specialization, namespace, parameter pack, and this." So yes, class members are not objects!

Comment: @rodvi unions are classes, but classes are not unions. Int is a type, but a type is not int.

Comment: IMO a variable template specialization may well be an object. But not always

Comment: @JohannesSchaub-litb But what's wrong? That page doesn't claim something like "objects are not class members". They directly claim that "class members are not objects".

Comment: @Rodvi ah you are right. Well, I think things are not so clear. What is clear, is that one can't just take the list in clause 3, and say that each item is non-overlapping with each other, which seems to be what cppreference is doing. For sure, a (class-) template-specialization is a type. Both are in the list. And a (function-) template-specialization is a function. And "this" is a value, and so on.

Comment: I found where this matters: attempting to explicitly capture a nonstatic data member in a lambda fails with both clang and gcc saying only variables can be captured.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> So their definition of non-static data member is wrong

Yes, it was wrong to use the word "variable" in the introductory sentence of the data members page (and, as mentioned in the comment, it's a wiki, the discussion tabs on wiki pages get faster feedback).

The current standard wording is `3[basic]/6` and :

> A variable is introduced by the declaration of a reference other than a non-static data member or of an object. The variable’s name, if any, denotes the reference or object.

So, reference data members are excluded explicitly, and to figure out the rest you need the definition of "object" from `1.8[intro.object]/1`

> An object is created by a definition (3.1), by a new-expression (5.3.4), when implicitly changing the active member of a union (9.3), or when a temporary object is created (4.4, 12.2).

And finally `3.1[basic.def]/2`

> A declaration is a definition unless ... it declares a non-inline static data member in a class definition (9.2, 9.2.3),

Although it may seem like the distinction between variables and data members is impractical language-lawyerism, it is actually important when understanding compiler diagnostics, at least in this case:

```
struct X {
    int m;
    void f() { auto l = [m](){ return m; }; }
};
```

gcc:

```
error: capture of non-variable 'X::m'
```

clang:

```
error: 'm' in capture list does not name a variable
```

icc:

```
error: member "X::m" is not a variable
```

Comment: I think they are also created by `throw`?

Comment: @Cubbi I'm still confused. So in `struct Y { int m1; int& m2; };` both m1 and m2 are not variables? If so, which part of  "_ A variable is introduced by the declaration of a reference other than a non-static data member or of an object._" covers this?

Comment: @Cheshar the part "other than a non-static data member"

Comment: If that's the case then in your answer '_So, reference data members are excluded explicitly, and to figure out the rest you need the definition of "object"_' what is the "_rest_" that needs to be figured out then?

Comment: @Cubbi Because when you say "_reference data members are excluded explicitly_" while quoting 3[basic]/6 then I don't think _"other than a non-static data member"_ covers the case of non-static non-reference data members. If that's the case, how do you conclude non-static, non-reference data members are not variables?

Comment: @Cheshar let me rephrase slightly, in your case, m2 is not a variable by 3[basic]/6 as quoted "declaration of a reference other than a non-static data member". To see why m1 is not a variable you combine the rest of that sentence ("declaration of ... an object") with the other two quotes.

Comment: @Cubbi But "_A declaration is a definition unless ... it declares a **non-inline static data member** in a class definition_" only talks about "non-inline static data member". It doesn't say anything about "non-static data member", which is what "m1" is. On the contrary, it leads me to infer that in `struct Y { int m1; int& m2; static int m3; };` "m3" is not a variable unless it is defined outside the class. Which brings up an interesting point - is name "m3" inside the class any different from a definition of "m3" outside the class? So the question remains...

Comment: [cont.] ...how is it inferred that non-static data member is not a variable? What am I missing?

Comment: @Cheshar OK, I see what you mean.  Will get back to this when I have a chance